# We are seeing below strange behaviour issue in our instance

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-apps

We are seeing below strange behaviour issue in our instance-

1. when we are running our scheduled concurrent programs. 
   Instead of program going to the desired manager it goes to the different manager and then it errored out with the below error.

Error:

> Routine `CALL_STORED_PROCEDURE` cannot initialize concurrent request 
>   Routine `AFPEOT` cannot initialize concurrent request information

We checked the controlling manager process id in `FND_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` table and we don't see any process it shows null.

2. when some of the concurrent programs for e.g. Customer Interface are assigned to the concurrent manager the actual process of manager are going down and when we are cancelling the program the actual processes are coming back up again. 
   The actual process keeps on varying from target process sometimes less and sometimes 0. 
   This is again the intermittent issue. We could not recognize any patter as such.

Tried bouncing database , application, services but nothing help.

Error:

> ORA-600 in database

Comment: ORA-600 is an Oracle bug, which means the full error message will not be displayed in the application.  You'll need to look at the Oracle alert log to find all of the parameters.  The first parameter of the error is usually the most helpful.  If Google doesn't help, you can use support.oracle.com, search for the "ora-600 tool", and input that first parameter.  There will usually be a few documents with information about the error.

Comment: Thank you Jon for responding: I saw a deadlock in alert log. Please suggest what scenarios we can check regarding this issue.

Comment: Every deadlock creates a separate trace file on the server.  If you look in that trace file it will tell you the relevant SQL statements and objects that caused the deadlock.  Most deadlocks are application issues, where two sessions are locking resources in a different order.